# Migration to new technology

Tags: wpf, html, winforms, winforms-to-web

My org is currently in Winforms and we are renegineering our complete system which has following parts
 - It is a heavy businesslogic desktop application
 - Should support part on web/multiple devices (handheld)
 - Part of it to be exposed as enterprise solution.

To define the target system, platform and language for such a system (timeline are to create by mid of 2016)
1. Can I replace heavy Desktop application with MS Application?
2. Should I create such DS Application with .net 4.0 WPF? (I am currently on Winforms so to me moving from Winforms to WPF or HTML5 is same)
3. I would prefer to move to HTML5 for the reason that my web, devices and desktop applocations are taken care - but do not have a path for DSA + HTML5 with WinRT

Please advice. Any other solution/suggestion also is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what direction your company wants to go.

If you want to go down the desktop only route, then yes, **WPF** should suit your requirements. I would suggest using the **MVVM Design Pattern**, with the **Repository/Unit Of Work Pattern**.

If you want to go towards the Desktop/Tablet/Mobile route, then you have the option of developing an **Windows App**, or a **Website Application**.

For a **Windows App**, you're looking at developing Microsoft Store Apps (I'd suggest a **Universal App**). If you want to do this, you might as well wait for Windows 10 to be released, as universal apps have grown up since 8.1.

That leaves **Web Applications**. There are a myriad of options to choose from here, most common of those would probably be **ASP.NET**, and things like **AngularJS**. Please note that I'm not saying that these technologies are the *best*, but they are just a couple of options. It's really up to you to research the frameworks and libraries that suit your requirements.

But like I said, it really depends on what your company wants their application to do, and what devices will be compatible.